# How to extract specific properties from each JSON object using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I have a JSON dataset

```
[{"key":"Albania",
    "values":[{                                                                  
        "Country_Names":"Albania",
        "Total":"3.8",
        "Change_total":"-38.7",
        "Main activity electricity and heat production":"0.1",
        "Main activity electricity plants":"","Main activity CHP plants":"",
        "Unallocated autoproducers / Other energy industry own use":"0.1",
        "Other":"1.4",
        "Manufacturing industries and construction":"1",
        "Iron and steel":"0","Chemical and petrochemical":"0","Machinery":"",
        "Mining and quarrying":"",
        "Food and tobacco":"0.1",
        "Paper, pulp and printing":"",
        "Construction":"0",
        "Transport":"2.2",
        "Road":"2.2",
        "Domestic aviation":"",
        "Rail":"0",
        "Domestic navigation":"0.1",
        "Residential":"0.2",
        "Commercial and public services":"0",
        "Agriculture/forestry":"0.2",
        "Sub-bituminous coal / Lignite":"",
        "Other bituminous coal":"",
        "Natural gas":"0",
        "Motor gasoline excl. bio":"0.3",
        "Gas/diesel oil excl. bio":"2.2"
    }]
}]
```

I want to extract specific values (Road, Rail for example) from each key (country) and draw an individual pie chart form each object. For example one chart for Albania that shows Road and Rail value and then same chart fro the next country in the data set.

I am trying to achieve this with the following code:

```
function checkIt(data) {
    var countriesByName = d3.nest()
    .key(function(d) { return d.Country_Names; })
    .entries(data);
    //console.log(countriesByName)
    var data = JSON.stringify(countriesByName);
    console.log(data);
    function makePie() {
        function myfunc(data){
            var obj =  [];
            for (var i in data.key) {
                obj.push('Road' + m.countriesByName[i].key.values[i].Food+ ' and tobacco');
            }
        }
        var data1 =  myfunc(data);
        //console.log(data)
        var chart = c3.generate({
            bindto: "#left",
            data: {
                columns: [
                data1
                ],type : "donut" 
            }
        });
    }
    makePie();
};
d3.json("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/heenaI/cbbc5c5f49994f174376/raw/82cd19eff7db367193cf8ce00144a40ea8d140ac/data.json", checkIt);
```

and I get the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

here is the [JS fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n5v84svm/30/) for the dataset:

The expected result is something like this ["Road", 2.2] I then want to run it as loop for all countries inside the data to get similar arrays

Comment: `array.map` would be your friend for actually modifying your array into the final result. And `array.reduce` for turning your `values` array into something. For example summing all the `rail` values.

Comment: What kind of data object does your chart plugin expect... ???   ,, You are supposed to construct json that your chart is expecting and send it as argument

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/n5v84svm/32/ => undefined ; `data.key` don't work like you expect I think...

Comment: looking into the code and the error further, It seems to be expecting a 2D array where you have `columns` in the data object.

Comment: I've been fiddling with it and, `columns: [[data1]],` making it into a 2D array DOES get rid of the error, now the question is what is it supposed to look like? what kind of data? Is the fiddle all of your code?

Comment: I think you forgot parse your data to JSONObject. Under `var data = JSON.stringify(countriesByName)` write `var data = JSON.parse(data);`

Comment: You're trying to get key atribute from a string, first of all convert your string to JSONObject to acces data.

Comment: Look now http://jsfiddle.net/f835g4du/

Comment: @Sean_A91, The data should look something like this inside column ["Road", 2.2], ["Rail", 0], only for one country and then It takes data from all json

Comment: @NischalKumarBC: See updated question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have forgotten parse your json string to JSONObject, for this reason you can't access to `key` property from string.

Under `var data = JSON.stringify(countriesByName);` you have to parse your object like this:

`var data = JSON.parse(data);`

Once you have done this, you can acces to your JSONObject properties.

Check this [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kp1qt0yv/).

Comment: Thank you for your answer what I really want to get is the values of Rail, Road inside my data with the result if something like this ["Road", 2.2], ["Rail", 0] and then run this as loop for all objects inside the dataset. The demo jsut gives me country names, when I try to get the values inside it returns undefined

Comment: Thank you for this.. I think I understand what I need to do.. but this one right now just sends data for all countries at once but what I wanted was that it takes Road data from country_1 => draws a pie => goes back takes data from country 2 => draws a pie... country n => draws pie of country n. I think I have to do something like this you can guide me if I am going in the wrong direction http://jsfiddle.net/1dtr3ht3/4/

Comment: Do you want to draw all pies at the same time, or do you want to select one pie and then draw it?

Comment: I will select name of the country with a drop down menu and then create a pie

Comment: But as of now I would just create see if it creates a pie for each country